# Viber unnamed subtask prevent Windows 10 shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, viber

When I shutdown my Windows 10 PC-s (laptop and desktop) an unnamed task prevent to shutdown it. After the timeout, the second attempt is successful without doing anything, just push the power button again.
If I switch off the automatic startup for Viber or close the task from the task manager the Windows closes normally and switches off my computers.
Does anybody know any solution for this?

Comment: Same here, on both of my machines. I've opened a [support ticket](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/emails/new), you can too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case reinstalling with the latest version (7.0) from the website fixed the problem. Now the task just flashes in the shutdown screen and is successfully terimnated.

After contacting Viber support, they pointed me that I am using very old version of the Windows client (5.9 or similar). The strange thing is that in the past I always upgraded to the versions suggested by the Settings gear in the top right corner- and that's where they led me.

Comment: I am using the version 6.9.6. This isn't an old version. The Viber didn't tell me anything about the new version. I am going to try it now.

Comment: Thx. It helped.